# Django - Createview form_valid object.id error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to create a form where the object created (a project) has a relationship with another model (the channel). The problem is I can't workout how to call the channel's primary key for the project's relationship.

**Models.py:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(
        'Channel',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

**Views.py:**

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name', 'description']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        Project = form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.channel = Channel.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['channel'])
        Project.channel = channel

        return super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I think something else needs to be added to the forms.py file as well:

**Forms.py:**

```
class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should use a `ModelForm` so that you can save it to create the instance. Don't include `channel` in the fields, because you're going to set it in the view.

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Project
         fields = ['name', 'description']
```

Then, assuming that your url pattern is correctly configured to include the channel, all you need to do is set the `channel` on the form instance and call the parent class' `form_valid` method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.channel = Channel.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['channel'])
    return super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Okay I've changed it to how you say it should be done and I'm still getting the same problem. My URL's are set up so they are pulling in a slug rather than a primary key, could that be whats upsetting this at the moment? 

The project creation form was working okay until I changed the channel URL's to slugs rather than the PK btw.

*edit* the current url for the form:

`url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/project/create/$', channel_views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='project_form'),`

Comment: You need to change the query in your view so that it matches your url pattern, e.g. `get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])`

Comment: Thank you so much! I cant believe I didnt realise that.